# FlutterLab: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using FlutterLab but encounter the below error:

```
⭐ Build started at Tuesday, August 31st 2021, 10:55:04AM +10:00 ⭐ 

  Build finished at Tuesday, August 31st 2021, 10:55:15AM +10:00  

 ❌ Build failed. Check the logs below 

Compile failed

/lib/main.dart:24:21: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.

Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.

  const MyDiary({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

                    ^

No branch
```

with the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Application name
      title: 'Flutter Hello World',
      // Application theme data, you can set the colors for the application as
      // you want
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // A widget which will be started on application startup
      home: MyDiary(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDiary extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDiary({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` in `pubspecs.yml`